# Wpf data templating - How do I access the parent of an item in an ItemsControl?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm in a weird situation.  I am generating a list of items grouped by specific categories.  In my view model, I have the items stored in an instance of `ReadOnlyDictionary<string, List<CustomObject>>`, where `CustomObject` represents the class that I created to store each list item.  The string is the category.  In my view, I have a `StackPanel` with an `<ItemsControl>` inside it.  The items control has an `ItemTemplate` which sort of looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateName">
    <StackPanel>
        <Separator />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" />
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Value}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

The bindings above work great.  The problem is that I don't want a separator above the first item.  So I guess I need a different style for the first item.

I've tried using an `ItemTemplateSelector`, but the problem is that it only has access to the current item, so it has no way of knowing of whether or not it is on the first element.  I also tried doing something like

```
<Separator 
    Visibility={Binding ShowSeparator, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type CustomObject}}}" />
```

...where ShowCategories is a dependency property in the CustomObject class which looks at the ReadOnlyDictionary instance and says whether or not to show separators.  But ShowCategories is never accessed when I do this.  I think even if it was, it would have no way of knowing which item is calling it.

So.  What do I do?

Comment: You can add a DataTrigger to the Separator style that will collapse the  separator if the first item is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the MVVM approach:

1. Have a **CustomObjectViewModel** kept in your Dictionary instead of your CustomObject, with your **CustomObject as it's Model**.
2. In the CustomObjectViewModel have access to a **CustomObjectService** (or a reference to the Dictionary for simplicity).
3. In the mentioned Service, have a method similar to:

   `Public Boolean IsCustomObjectFirst(CustomObjectViewModel vm){..}`

   That will, obviously, check for the given item's position.
4. now simply have a property `ShouldDisplaySeperator` in your **CustomObjectViewModel**, that will get it's value from `CustomObjectService.IsCustomObjectFirst(this)`
5. now simply use it in your View's definition, using something similar to:

   View Definition:

   ```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateName">
       <StackPanel>
           <Separator Visibilty="{Binding ShouldDisplaySeperator,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Key}" />
           <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Model.Value}" />
       </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
   ```

Comment: No problem, did it resolve your issue ? or does the answer need adjusting ?

Comment: I'm just now getting a chance to try it.  I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without the need to add new properties in your VM or using an `ItemTemplateSelector`.

I'd prefer to keep this in xaml alone as it's just View related and nothing to do with any logic that needs "testing"

So a xaml solution could be to use the [ItemsControl.AlternationIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationindex.aspx)

something like:

```
<ListBox AlternationCount="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ItemsSource.Count, Mode=OneWay}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
        <Separator x:Name="seperator" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" />
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Value}" />
      </StackPanel>
      <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(ListBox.AlternationIndex),
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                                      AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"
                      Value="0">
          <Setter TargetName="seperator"
                  Property="Visibility"
                  Value="Hidden" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Two key parts to this snippet.

- We assign the `AlternationCount` on the `ListBox` the same as the `ItemSource.Count` to thereby generate a unique `AlternationIndex` on each `ListBoxItem`.
- `DataTemplate.DataTrigger` just checks the current item to see if it's `AlternationIndex` is 0 and if so hides the `seperator`.